# Unable to Access Azure VM behind Firewall after installing Docker

Tags: azure, docker, firewall

I have an Azure Ubuntu 20.04 VM behind Firewall.
I was able to access the VM via SSH until I started installing Docker.

When I was mid-way through, the installation stopped and I lost connectivity to the VM.

I am unable to find anything.

I have restarted the VM, checked for connectivity troubleshooting, nothing came up.

How can I access the VM again?

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux-vm-connect?tabs=Linux) and use Azure Cloud Shell from browser to connect to your VM and check the firewalls rules, I think you used an ready to go script to install docker and that closed port 22 (the port that ssh using).

Comment: No. I installed Docker step by step and had port 22 open.